# is the usage of "only" to stress my point is correct in the below context?

Tags: sentence-structure

Context: The client asked us to email him some information for the last 3 years. But there are some problems with it :
Firstly, we have information for the past eight months.
Secondly, The information was exchanged via emails. So, it is quite difficult to extract that information from emails of past 8-9 months.

> We have two major issues with the information requested.
>
> 1. We **only** have information for the last 8 months. We do not have
>      any records prior to that.
>
>    *(**Is there anything I can use other than "only" to stress my point in
>      the first line**. )*
> 2. The information for the last eight months was exchanged via emails. There's no consolidated report that recorded the information.
>      We would have to fetch that information from the emails.

Comment: @shin I have made some changes in my question. Could you please check it again to see if it meets the guidelines of the site so that the question can be removed from being on hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**only** can be used as you do. You can also say

> ... information for the last eight months only.
>
> ... information for only the last eight months.

There are a number of ways of stating that fact without using the word **only**. For example:

> The information we have does not go back any further than eight months.

With respect to the email:

> The information you requested exists only in the form of emails. To **glean** it from them would be very time-consuming.  You could also use the verb **extract** instead of *glean* there.

With respect to the issue of laziness and incompetence:

> We would be happy to send you copies of these emails.

If you make that offer, you don't even have to mention extracting the information unless your client responds and says he is not satisfied with copies of those emails.